# Compare class type without instance

Tags: c#, .net, exception, generics, types

I have a 'factory' class that should compare the generic class type parameter and return a specific instance of an object:

```
public static class MyExceptionFactory<T> where T: System.Exception {
    public static MyReturnObj Create() {
        // return instance of MyReturnObj based on type of T
    }
}
```

But I can't check if e.g. T is `ArgumentNullException` because T is a type parameter and not a variable

```
if(T is ArgumentNullException) // won't work
```

.. and also, I can't check for the type of T

```
if(typeof(T) is ArgumentNullException)
```

because IntelliSense tells me that T is never `System.ArgumentNullException` (I assume because T is `System.Exception`)

How could I solve this? Do I have to pass an instance of a `System.Exception` to check it's type or is there any other way to do it via class type parameter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two type identifiers, you just need to compare the types.

```
if(typeof(T) == typeof(ArgumentNullException))
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: But that's what `is` is for. :)

Comment: @Atrotygma: The `is` operator can only be used on instances like `if(myObject is SomeType)`.

Comment: No, the "is" keyword checks whether an instance of a type can be cast to another type without an exception. So first, you would need an instance to use "is" to begin with.

Comment: `where T: System.Exception, new()` and `var ex = new T();` fixed it. Maybe a bit uneccessary to create an instance, but it does the job with `is` then. Thanks for your help - obviously I need some sleep. :/

Comment: @Atrotygma Yes, it is unneccessary to create an instance and have a constraint for it. You can use typeof. It's the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 3):

If inherited types should be respected, use:

```cs
if(typeof(ArgumentNullException).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(ArgumentNullException))
{
    //your code
}
```